# Is Facebook Login now required to use the facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I developed a site that uses the older version of the facebook api, I did not implement Facebook Login to access the site.  They recently updated all apps to use the new api and require an application process to continue to use the api.

After submitting my application it was rejected and I was told " Please integrate Facebook Login".  This was not a requirement before.  Is it now required to use the api?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you need to implement Facebook Login to use permissions. Those permissions need to get authorized with the scope parameter in the login process and Facebook needs to test how you use those permissions if you want to get them approved.

Comment: Adding to what luschn said, if you are planing to only use this app yourself (or with a very limited user base, that could be added as an admin/developer/tester), then you do not need to submit for review.